Angular - Component making duplicate api 'GET' requests with behaviorsubject
I am working on an angular v14 application and I am having trouble figuring out how to fix an issue with my component making duplicate api calls.
I have a service that is shared between all components to set and retrieve state values. The value needed for the api call has an initial value set to be able to make the request when the component initializes.
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private type$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('some-tab-value');

  setType(type: string) {
    this.type$.next(libraryType);
  }

  getType() {
    return this.type$.asObservable();
  }
}


I have a top level component that sets the BehaviorSubject value whenever a user clicks a tab on the page with the tab value;
import { SharedService } from './services/shared.service';

export class TopLevelComponent {
  private initialValue = 'some value';

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

  onTabClick(type) {
    this.sharedService.setType(type);
  }
}

I have another component that subscribes to the tab value clicked in the top level component. It is needed to make an api call.
import { SharedService} from '../../services/shared.service';
import { SomeService } from './services/some.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class SomeOtherComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscriptionList: Subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(
    private sharedService: SharedService,
    private someService: SomeService
  ) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptionList.add(
      this.sharedService.getType().pipe(
        switchMap(selectedType => {
          // some api call
          return this.someService.getStuff(selectedType)
        })
      ).subscribe(value => {
         // this value is always logging twice when the component loads
         // also logs twice when clicking on tab in UI
         console.log(value)
       )
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptionList.unsubscribe();
  }
}

The service that is handling the http requests look something like this
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getStuff(type) {
    return this.httpClient.get('some-url').pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(() => new Error('Error while fetching stuff: ' + err));
      }
    )
  }

}

I think it has to do with the BehaviorSubject emitting the last and current values. I tried switching the BehaviorSubject into a Subject instead. However, since a Subject doesn't take an initial value, I tried to set the initial value in the ngOnInit function inside the top level component. The other component does not fire the http request until the user clicks on a tab (but i want it to also fire when initializing).
I feel like this should be an easy fix but I have been stuck trying to resolve this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

You forgot to unsubscribe it, always make sure whenever you are using subscribe, implement a OnDestroy interface and add method ngOnDestroy and destroy your subscription inside it.

I updated the code sample because I did forget to include it. But yes, even unsubscribing in ngOnDestroy, it was still giving me this issue.

When the component is destroyed make sure you unsubscribe the subscription to the BehaviourSubject, else it will continue to live and cause memory leaks, even if the component is destroyed.
import { SharedService} from '../../services/shared.service';
import { SomeService } from './services/some.service';

export class SomeOtherComponent implements OnInit {
  private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService, private someService: SomeService) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub.add(
      this.sharedService.getType().pipe(
        switchMap(selectedType => {
          // some api call
          return this.someService.getStuff(selectedType)
        })
      ).subscribe(value => {
         // this value is always logging twice when the component loads
         // also logs twice when clicking on tab in UI
         console.log(value)
      })
    );
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}


I forgot to include that in the code sample, but yes I did unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy already and still have the issue.

@mobes Please share a minimal reproducible stackblitz where the issue happens, you might find the issue when trying to replicate the issue!

The reason you are getting two console outputs is because the BehaviourSubject you are observing is emitting it's value twice. Once when you are subscribed and once when you call your setType function. That is how BehaviourSubject works. Check out https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject
For your use case, you could opt for a normal Subject which will emit a value once on change and have a default tab selected in the UI. What is the reason you need to emit an initial value as soon as you subscribe?

I was able to resolve the issue and find out why this was happening. It had nothing to do with the way I was using the BehaviorSubject, but had to do with the component structure of my app.
My routing was as follows.
{
    path: 'top-level',
    component: TopLevelComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child1',
        component: Child1Component,
      },
      {
        path: 'child2',
        component: Child2Component,
      },
  }

Inside each of these child components templates, I was rendering a reusable component 'SomeOtherComponent'.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
})
export class Child1Component {
  constructor() {}
}

<div class="child1">
  <app-some-other-component></app-some-other-component>
  <div>HTML exclusive to child 1</div>
</div>

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child2',
  templateUrl: './child2.component.html',
})
export class Child2Component {
  constructor() {}
}

<div class="child2">
  <app-some-other-component></app-some-other-component>
  <div>HTML exclusive to child 2</div>
</div>

Every time the TopLevelComponent emitted the tab change from UI click, it would destroy one of the child components and render the other. The issue is that 'SomeOtherComponent' was getting the subscription value twice, as if it wasn't actually getting destroyed. What I needed to do was put 'SomeOtherComponent' in the top level so that it wasn't being rendered in each child component.
Like this
<div class="top-level">
  <app-some-other-component></app-some-other-component>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

